# Laravel + htaccess not allowing access to directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, server

to remove /public/ from laravel , I used the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.comn$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

But the issue is now that I can't even access files saved under site.com/files/image.png or anything like that. It shows me 404 page.

How to modify htaccess to allow access to some directories. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are redirecting everything to /public/. You need to exclude your existent dirs and files from the redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.comn$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm not good with mod_rewrite. Can you tell me how to do it for instance if I have a directory named /files/ on root?

Comment: @kirobo sorry, there was a typo in my answer,  the edit  should work

Comment: Yes! Thanks. It allows to download directories. But now when I go to my main domain site.com - I can see directory listing and I have to again go to site.com/public/ to see the site. :( Can we do it like this everything remains same just allow files to be downloaded without showing 404.

Comment: Works perfectly! :) Thank you sir. I owe you a drink. :)